# onLoad scroll until div centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a menu, that scroll to `current div` and that div is on center of menu. I made a little example, but its goes too far from center.
In my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/4g0mz6t0/2/) you can see it.

There's my JQuery

```
  var scrollNav = ".page-nav .nav-content";
  var currentNavItem = ".page-nav .items .item.current";
  var currentPos = $(currentNavItem).position().left;
  $(scrollNav).animate({scrollLeft: currentPos}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to factor in width of the entire area and width of your item.

```js
var scrollNav = ".page-nav .nav-content";
  var currentNavItem = ".page-nav .items .item.current";
  var currentPos = $(".item.current").position().left + $(".item.current").width()/2 - $(scrollNav).width()/2;
  $(scrollNav).animate({scrollLeft: currentPos}, 500);
```

```css
.page-nav{
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    background: white;
}

.page-nav .nav-content{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 864px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

.page-nav .items{
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:200%;
}

.page-nav .items .item{
    display: inline-block;
}

.page-nav .items .item a{
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.page-nav .items .item.current a{
    color: #0099ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-nav">
        <div class="nav-content">
            <div class="items">
                <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 1</a></div>
                <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 2</a></div>
                <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 3</a></div>
                <div class="item current"><a href="">Menu item 4</a></div>
                <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 5</a></div>
                <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 6</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove half of the width of the container and add half width of your el. Just changed your sample:

```
  var scrollNav = ".page-nav .nav-content";
  var currentNavItem = ".page-nav .items .item.current";
  var currentPos = $(currentNavItem).position().left + $(currentNavItem).width()/2 - $(scrollNav).width()/2;
  $(scrollNav).animate({scrollLeft: currentPos}, 500);
```